# Cannot find an overload for XCTAssertEqual that accepts an argument list of type ([String : AnyObject], [String : AnyObject])

Tags: swift, xctest

I have one method:

```
func tableAsDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject]
```

Then I need to test this:

```
let tableDictionary = table.tableAsDictionary()

let expectedDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "Next to window",
    "number": 23
]

XCTAssertEqual(tableDictionary, expectedDictionary) //error
```

> Cannot find an overload for `XCTAssertEqual` that accepts an argument list of type `[String : AnyObject], [String : AnyObject]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `==` operator for dictionaries requires that
both the key and the value type is `Equatable`:

```
func ==<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>(lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool
```

but `AnyObject` does not conform to `Equatable`.

A simple fix is to replace the dictionary type `[String: AnyObject]`
 by `[String : NSObject]`, then your  code compiles without problems.